# Find closest county in a list to a county

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've been working through some reverse geocoding problems.

After a user searches for a location I pull the county from the geocode result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
    var component = results[0].address_components[i];
    if (component.types[0] == "administrative_area_level_2") {
        var county = component.long_name;            
    }
countySearch(county);
}
```

Next, I have a JSON of counties that I would like to search using a function we'll call countySearch.

```
function countySearch(county){  
    $.each(countyJSON, function(i){     
        if(countyJSON[i].county==county)
        {           
            console.log('math at row' + i);
        }
        else if(i==chapters.length-1 && chapters[i].ZIP!=zipCode)
        {
            console.log('no match in JSON');
            findNearestCounty(county);
        }       
    });         
}
```

If there is no match in the JSON I then want to find which of the counties is the next closest.  I would do this using a function called findNearestCounty.  Any suggestions on how to find the next nearest county in the JSON?  I figure I could add a lat/lng field to the JSON and go about it that way but wanted to see if anyone had a better idea.

thanks,

j

Comment: It's easy to find the distance between two points, not so trivial to find the distance to an irregular border.

Comment: can you put your JSON file too?

Comment: You said "could add a lat/lng field to the JSON", do you have _any_ location data in the JSON?  To find the "closest county", you will need some idea of where the county is (either a polygon or a centroid) and some idea of where the comparison location is.

Comment: that's what I figured.  I will create some points in each county and then match my search location to the nearest point (county).  I was hoping there would be some slick way to do it using Google's geocoder

Comment: If you are working solely with one US state, then you could by hand craft a JSON object that has a list of counties and for each, a set of adjacent counties.